# Rails: Devise: redirect after sign in by role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Is it possible to redirect users to different pages (based on role) after signing in with Devise?  It only seems to redirect to the root :to => ... page defined in routes.rb

Answer (score 48, accepted):

By default Devise does route to root after it's actions. There is a nice article about overriding these actions on the Devise Wiki, https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in

Or you can go even farther by setting `stored_locations_for(resource)` to nil, and then have different redirects for each action, ie: `after_sign_up_path(resource)`, `after_sign_in_path(resource)` and so on.

Comment: Right on. If you look at the Registrations Controller for Devise itself you can see all of the different methods in there, and can then override any of them at will.

Comment: @janders223 how can you gain access to the registration controller for devise?

Comment: No luck for me :(

Comment: I believe it's after after_sign_in_path_for

Answer (score 35):

You can simply add this method to your application controller:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  user_path(current_user) # your path
end
```

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to figure out how to redirect someone at initial login to go to a News page.  After that the Home functionality returns to normal.  This is what I ended up using for my code:

~~~
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if current_user.role == 'admin'
      start_path
    else
      news_path
    end
  end
~~~
Thank You!!

Answer (score 11):

Devise has a helper method `after_sign_in_path_for` which can be used to override the default Devise route to root after login/sign-in.

To implement a redirect to another path after login, simply add this method to your application controller.

```
#class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  users_path
end
```

Where users_path is the path that you want it to redirect to, **User** is the model name that corresponds to the model for Devise.

**Note**: If you used **Admin** as your model name for Devise, then it will be

```
#class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  admins_path
end
```

**Also**, if you generated controllers for Devise, then you can define this in the **sessions controller**, say, your Devise model is `Admin`, you can define this in the `app/controllers/admins/sessions_controller.rb` file to route to the `dashboard_index_path`:

```
# app/controllers/admins/sessions_controller.rb'

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  dashboard_index_path
end
```

And in the **registrations controller** - `app/controllers/admins/registrations_controller.rb` file:

```
# app/controllers/admins/registrations_controller.rb

def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  dashboard_index_path
end
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 5):

You can use the below code in the application controller or any controller where you need to do the operation:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    users_path
end
```

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in,-sign-up,-or-sign-out

I used example 1:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :authenticate_user!

  protected

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    current_user.is_a?(Admin) ? admin_tests_path : (stored_location_for(resource) || root_path)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the answer provided by @Asnad Atta

Here is what I ended up using.

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if current_user.role == 'admin'
      start_path
    else
      news_path
    end
  end
```

I wanted everyone who logs in to first be pushed to a News page.
After the initial login the Home on the Navbar goes to the start_path (just what I call it in my app).  The start_path is also in my root to:

This wonderful after_sign_in_path_for(resource) over rides the root to: path ONLY on the initial Login.

This is exactly what I wanted.

I hope this can help save someone some time.
Scott

Answer (score -3):

Here's what I believe is the answer you are looking for from the devise wiki:

[How To: Change the default sign_in and sign_out routes](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes)

Comment: The question asks about redirecting **after** sign in, whereas this link discusses changing the routes for signing in and out itself (i.e. creating and destroying a session)