# Ruby on Rails - Devise always redirect to the root_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

In my Ruby on Rails Application I use devise for authenticate the "admins".

I'm using only the "Admin" model so i modified the 'routes.rb' file for define my custom routes of the site

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :contacts

  devise_for :admins

  #Personal Devise admin routes
  as :admin do

    #Session Block
    get "/login" => "devise/sessions#new",  :as => :admin_session_login
    delete "/logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy", :as => :admin_logout

    #Account Block
    get "/register" => "devise/registrations#new", :as => :admin_register
    get "/edit_account" => "devise/registrations#edit", :as => :admin_edit

  end
end
```

I saved the file and restarted the server but when i try to navigate to one of this custom routes like '/login' the application redirect me to http://localhost:3000/

i also post the server console log when i try to navigate to /login:

**console server log**

```
  Started GET "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-29 18:15:32 +0200
      ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
    Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
      Admin Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "admins".* FROM "admins" WHERE "admins"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "admins"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
    Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
    Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
    Completed 302 Found in 46ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms

)
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638920/redirect-after-sign-in-with-devise

Comment: Please post your `after_sign_in_path_for`method.

Answer (score 0):

I can not add a comment.
If you have logined, you will always be redirected to root_path. And you can try another path to find out.

Answer (score 0):

to change the default devise redirect path just add this method
in your application controller

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)

  yourpathname_path(resource)

end
```