# Devise: Redirect to Admin Path After Successful Login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've created a separate Devise log-in form to login to my Admin interface. The log-in itself works fine. How do I specify a different redirect action after a successful log-in? The documentation only states how to change the global redirect action.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect after sign in with Devise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638920/redirect-after-sign-in-with-devise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can check role also

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if (###check current_user is admin ###)
     ### your redirection ###
    else
     ### other redirection ###
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Redirect does not seem to work. I get DoubleRenderError when I try that.

Comment: Got it: store_location_for(resource, admin_root_path) worked for me.