# Rails 4/5 devise gem redirect after Login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm pretty new in Rails. I'm trying to use devise gem to sign up and sign in users, and I would like to redirect users after login to another view (called page) that I have on the views folder of same project directory.

This is how my routes.rb file looks at the moment:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'visitors#index'
  devise_for :users
  resources :users

  resources :page
end
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638920/redirect-after-sign-in-with-devise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `after_sign_in_path_for` method of your `SessionsController` to do that:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  root_path # <- The page you want redirect to after logged in
end
```

You can read more detail at [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update)

Hope it helps.